# In swift 5, how to retrieve the key of the second low value in a dictionary of [String: Float]?

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
var mydict: [String: Float] = ["aze": 22.4, "lkh": 42.04, etc ... ]
```

How to retrieve the key of the second low value in `mydict`?

Comment: Do you want to do that like if your dictionary was an array (by using indexes)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sorted(by:)` to sort the `Dictionary` into ascending order based on the values, then simply get the 2nd element from the sorted array of key-value pairs and access its `key` property.

```
var mydict: [String: Float] = ["aze": 22.4, "lkh": 42.04, "abc": 25.12 ]
let ascendingDict = mydict.sorted(by: { $0.value < $1.value })
let secondLowest = ascendingDict[1]
secondLowest.key // "abc"
```

Comment: You can use `ascendingDict.prefix(2).last` to avoid crashes (and to get an optional :) )

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution that also handles dictionaries that contain 1 element or less by returning nil in that case.

The solution is using a tuple of optional tuples (key/value) and the second lowest key is then found by using `reduce(into:)` on the dictionary

```
let secondLowest = mydict.reduce(((String, Float)?, (String,Float)?)(nil, nil)) {
    guard let first = $0.0 else {
        return ($1, nil)
    }
    guard let second = $0.1 else {
        if first.1 < $1.value { return (first, $1) }
        return ($1, first)
    }
    return $1.value < first.1 ? ($1, first) : ($1.value < second.1 ? (first, $1) : $0)
}.1?.0
```

this could also be expressed in an extension to Dictionary as a computed property

```
extension Dictionary where Value: Comparable {
    var keyForSecondLowest: Key? {
        self.reduce(((Key, Value)?, (Key,Value)?)(nil, nil)) {
            guard let first = $0.0 else {
                return ($1, nil)
            }
            guard let second = $0.1 else {
                if first.1 < $1.value { return (first, $1) }
                return ($1, first)
            }
            return $1.value < first.1 ? ($1, first) : ($1.value < second.1 ? (first, $1) : $0)
        }.1?.0
    }
}
```

Example

```
if let secondLowest = mydict.keyForSecondLowest {
    print(secondLowest)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is via pattern matching within `reduce()`:

```swift
let minims = mydict.reduce(into: ((String, Float)?.none, (String, Float)?.none)) {
    switch ($0.0?.1 ?? .infinity, $0.1?.1 ?? .infinity, $1.1) {
    case let (min1, _, val) where val < min1: $0 = ($1, $0.0)
    case let (_, min2, val) where val < min2: $0.1 = $1
    default: break
    }
}

print(minims.1?.0)
```

The algorithm is the same as the Joakim's one, and it works by computing a tuple of optional tuples, the first optional tuple corresponding to the minimal entry in the dictionary, while the second will correspond to the next minimal entry.

Note that if the dictionary has less than two elements then some of the result tuples will be nil.

Performance is linear, as it requires only one iteration of the dictionary.